# MongoDB setting using dot operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I've got a 3x deep object i'm trying to set with

This is the object starting out

```
{
    "_id": "53d905a709193fb6a0076fec",
    "active": 1,
    "article": null,
    "category_id": null,
    "clarification": null,
    "id": 5279,
    "language_id": 2,
    "master_id": 1667,
    "part_of_speech": "verb",
    "rank": 279,
    "word": "recordar",
    "hasSound": false,
    "extras": 0,
    "conjugations": {
        "present": [{
            "prefixes": {
                "1": "Yo"
            },
            "verb": "recuerdo",
            "grammar": "1PS"
        }],
        "preterite": [{
            "prefixes": {
                "1": "Yo"
            },
            "verb": "recordÃ©",
            "grammar": "1PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "2": "Tu"
            },
            "verb": "recordaste",
            "grammar": "2PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "3": "El",
                "4": "Ella",
                "6": "Usted"
            },
            "verb": "recordÃ³",
            "grammar": "3PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "7": "Nosotros"
            },
            "verb": "recordamos",
            "grammar": "1PP"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "9": "Ellos",
                "10": "Ellas",
                "11": "Ustedes"
            },
            "verb": "recordaron",
            "grammar": "3PP"
        }],
        "imperfect": [{
            "prefixes": {
                "1": "Yo"
            },
            "verb": "recordaba",
            "grammar": "1PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "2": "Tu"
            },
            "verb": "recordabas",
            "grammar": "2PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "3": "El",
                "4": "Ella",
                "6": "Usted"
            },
            "verb": "recordaba",
            "grammar": "3PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "7": "Nosotros"
            },
            "verb": "recordÃ¡bamos",
            "grammar": "1PP"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "9": "Ellos",
                "10": "Ellas",
                "11": "Ustedes"
            },
            "verb": "recordaban",
            "grammar": "3PP"
        }],
        "future": [{
            "prefixes": {
                "1": "Yo"
            },
            "verb": "recordarÃ©",
            "grammar": "1PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "2": "Tu"
            },
            "verb": "recordarÃ¡s",
            "grammar": "2PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "3": "El",
                "4": "Ella",
                "6": "Usted"
            },
            "verb": "recordarÃ¡",
            "grammar": "3PS"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "7": "Nosotros"
            },
            "verb": "recordaremos",
            "grammar": "1PP"
        }, {
            "prefixes": {
                "9": "Ellos",
                "10": "Ellas",
                "11": "Ustedes"
            },
            "verb": "recordarÃ¡n",
            "grammar": "3PP"
        }]
    }
}
```

This is the $set object. `collection.update({id: id}, {$set: obj})`;

```
var obj = {
    "conjugations.present.0.prefixes.1": "Yo",
    "conjugations.present.0.verb": "recuerdo",
    "conjugations.present.0.grammar": "1PS"
}
```

1

And then this is the object after the update

```
{
    "_id": "53d905a709193fb6a0076fec",
    "active": 1,
    "article": null,
    "category_id": null,
    "clarification": null,
    "id": 5279,
    "language_id": 2,
    "master_id": 1667,
    "part_of_speech": "verb",
    "rank": 279,
    "word": "recordar",
    "hasSound": false,
    "extras": 0,
    "conjugations": {
        "present": {
            "0": {
                "prefixes": {
                    "1": "Yo"
                },
                "verb": "recuerdo",
                "grammar": "1PS"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, conjugations is now an object, instead of an array, and it killed the rest of the conjugations object. From the docs it looks like I should be able to update specific parts of the full conjugations object using `"conjugations.present.0..."` but instead of setting the 0th array element it's setting it to an object with a key 0

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to use "$set" operator for your case. And instead of setting each key in `conjugations.present[0]`, why don't just redefine an entire `conjugations.present[0]` object? I suggest doing the following:

```
db.yourcollection.update(
    {_id : "someId"}, 
    {$set : {"conjugations.present.0" : 
            {
                "prefixes": {
                    "1": "Yo"
                },
                "verb": "recuerdo",
                "grammar": "1PS"
            }
        }
    }
)
```

This will modify the 0-th element in your `conjugations.present`. I imported your objects into my machine, worked for me.

Comment: So i am using $set, the reason I'm not setting the entire object is because this is an import script from a spreadsheet. So i'm looping over rows. Some data can already exist however, so I need to find the index and update that.

Comment: If I run my $set in robomongo it works, it just doesn't work when node-mongo driver runs it.

Comment: I should clarify that the loop is for the "prefixes" array inside. So 1 iteration might set "yo", but the next iteration might set "tu" which is just another prefix object

Comment: Figured it out, after i deleted the conjugations, i wasn't updating my object to be used for the loop.